# TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'document.getsElementsByClassName('')

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typeerror

```
Actual Error
```

TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'ActiveElem[i].hasClass('active');

```
HTML

<div class = 'Carousel-Inner'>
  <div class="morningSlide active">
    <img src="/Users/KO527/Sites/TarasDeli/TarasPhotos/EmployeeStoreOpening.jpg">
    <span class = 'time'>At<br>6:00 AM...</br></span>
    <p>Shop Opens up<br>Chefs prepare</br></p>
  </div>
  <div class = 'afternoonSlide'>
      <img src = '/Users/KO527/TarasDeli/TaraPhotos/CrowdedLunchTime.jpg'>
      <span class = 'time'>At <br>11:30 AM...</br>...12:00PM<br>...12:30PM</br>...1:00PM</span>
      <p><br>Students flood Deli</br>For Lunch</p>
  </div>
  <div class = 'ClosingTimes'>
      <img src = '/Users/KO527/TarasDeli/TaraPhotos/TarasNoTraffic.jpg'>
      <span class = 'time'>At <br>4:00 PM...</br></span>
      <p>Deli Closes</p>
  </div>
</div>


jQuery

function ActiveSpan(){
        if ($('.active span').left === '-500px'){
            $('.active span').animate({left: '25px', opacity: 1}, 750);
            }
        setTimeout(function(){$('.active span').stop().animate({left: '-500px', opacity: 0.1}, 1000)}, 5000);
}   

function ActiveP(){
        if ($('.active p').css('left') === '-500px'){
            $('.active p').stop().animate({left: '25px', opacity: 1}, 750);
            }
        setTimeout(function(){$('.active p').stop().animate({left: '-500px', opacity: 0.1}, 750)}, 5000);
}

function PullEmOut(){
    ActiveSpan();
    ActiveP();
}

function CarouselStroll(){
var ActiveElem = $('Carousel-Inner').find('div');
    for (var i = 0; i < ActiveElem.length; i++){
        if (ActiveElem[i].hasClass('active')){
            PullEmOut();
            ActiveElem[i].fadeOut(600).removeClass('active');
        }
        else {
            ActiveElem.filter('.active').removeClass('active');
            ActiveElem[0].addClass('active');
        }

        if (ActiveElem[i+1].length === 0){
            ActiveElem[0].fadeIn(600).addClass('active');
            PullEmOut();
        }
        else {
            ActiveElem[i+1].fadeIn(600).addClass('active');
        }   
    }
}
```

So the idea is for the function CarouselStroll() to have the div nodes inside of the 'Carousel-Inner' div placed inside of the ActiveElem variable which in turn is suppose to behave as an array. However when the code is run, the browser cannot seem to interpret the line where the browser is looking to see if the current div (the i variable) has the class 'active'->(if (ActiveElem[i].hasClass('active')). The error above is what is seen in the Safari console. Can somebody please help.

P.S -- Overall the function is suppose to cycle through the assigned array and check for and assign the 'active' class and render the PullEmOut function, which works just fine. For now I'm only concerned with the TypeError.

Comment: Typo? "gets" should be "get" `getsElementsByClassName()`

Comment: I apologize. The actual code has the correct spelling, but I still need the right solution.

Comment: Use jQuery's `$` selector to query your DOM objects.

Comment: Can you show some HTML so we can see what you're trying to loop through?

Comment: The html I am trying to loop through is at the top of what I originally posted

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByClassName returns a Node Set, it does not have a "children" method

Why are you not using jQuery

```
$(".Carousel-Inner").children()
```

If you did not want to use jQuery, you would need to loop over the set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jQuery's selector function `$`. jQuery returns a special jQuery object that provides the method `children` that you are trying to use.

```
$('.Carousel-Inner').children()
```

Read more about it here: [The jQuery Object](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/)